# debugging using xdebug and cakephp in eclipse PDT

Tags: php, cakephp, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I'm working on one web application.
I wanted to provide interactive debugging to my web application, so i have installed xdebug on my machine( windows ) successfully. Done with all the configuration settings in php.ini file. **I am able to debug normal php scripts except cakephp project.**

I hv used cakephp and eclipse IDE for development. 
I stuck @ one point that, for debugging in Eclipse using xdebug. I dont know how to set debug configuration in eclipse for cakephp specific.

Is there any other configuration settings needed in eclipse for debugging cakephp application using xdebug.

I gone though below url saying that need to delete .htaccess file in cakeProject\app\webroot and use another file which are under cakeProject\app.

http://cakephp.19694.n2.nabble.com/How-to-debug-with-ZendDebugger-XDebug-using-Eclipse-PDT-Netbeans-td1477152.html

Please folks suggest me if u hv any better ideas

Thanks

-Pravin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this tutorial a try.  It's using the Zend debugger not Xdebug but that really doesn't matter.

http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/debugging-cakephp-applications-in-zend-studio-for-eclipse-213/

Comment: great....i ll try this first, though it's related zend to debugger. I may get related things there for xdebug... Thanks